# Reference the default nat gateway?

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

just wondering how I can reference the NateGateway properly inside a Vpc Construct? I have a vpc with a default gateway.

```
    const thisVpc = new ec2.Vpc(this, vpcId, {
      cidr: cidrBlock,
      maxAzs: 2,
      natGateways: 1,
      subnetConfiguration: [
        { subnetType: subNetPublic, name: 'PUBLIC', cidrMask: 24 },
        { subnetType: subNetPrivate, name: 'PRIVATE', cidrMask: 24 },
      ],
    });
```

I thought I could reference the gateway like below:

```
 
    const igw = thisVpc.node.findChild('IGW') as ec2.CfnInternetGateway;

    const PublicRouteTable = new ec2.CfnRouteTable(this, 'PublicRT', {
      vpcId: thisVpc.vpcId,
    });

    const PublicRoute = new ec2.CfnRoute(this, 'PublicRoute', {
      routeTableId: PublicRouteTable.ref,
      natGatewayId: igw.logicalId, <--
      destinationCidrBlock: '0.0.0.0/0',
    });
```

But I keep getting an error when I try to deploy: Invalid id: "vpcxxx" (expecting "nat-...") (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidNatGatewayId.Mal
formed;

Not sure what I am doing wrong here. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to assign an Internet Gateway as a Nat Gateway property.

Based on the context, are you trying to attache the IGW to this public route table?

```js
const igw = thisVpc.node.findChild('IGW') as ec2.CfnInternetGateway;

const PublicRouteTable = new ec2.CfnRouteTable(this, 'PublicRT', {
    vpcId: thisVpc.vpcId,
});

const PublicRoute = new ec2.CfnRoute(this, 'PublicRoute', {
    routeTableId: PublicRouteTable.ref,
    gatewayId: igw.ref,  // <-- instead of natGatewayId
    destinationCidrBlock: '0.0.0.0/0',
});
```

Alternatively, to create a private route using the Nat Gateway, you'd do something like this

```js
const natgw = thisVpc.node.findChild('NATGateway') as ec2.CfnNatGateway;

const PrivateRouteTable = new ec2.CfnRouteTable(this, 'PrivateRT', {
    vpcId: thisVpc.vpcId,
});

const PrivateRoute = new ec2.CfnRoute(this, 'PrivateRoute', {
    routeTableId: PrivateRouteTable.ref,
    natGatewayId: natgw.ref,
    destinationCidrBlock: '0.0.0.0/0',
});
```